# $\| \gamma(b) - \gamma (a) \| \leq \mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([a,b]))$ if $\gamma$ is not rectifiable?

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I'm dealing with Hausdorff-Measure and the length of curves. It widely known that for a rectifiable continuous curve $\gamma:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ the inequasion
$$\| \gamma(b) - \gamma (a) \| \leq \mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([a,b]))$$
holds. But does it also hold if $\gamma$ ist not necessarily rectifiable?

Comment: I'm not too familiar, but if $\gamma$ isn't rectifiable, wouldn't the right hand side be infinite?

Comment: Not necessarily, for example the function $\gamma(t) = t \sin(t)$ for $t>0$ and $f(0) = 0$ on $[0,1]$ is bounded in $[-1,1]$, so $\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([0,1])) = \mathcal{H}^1([-1,1]) = 2$, but not rectifiable.

Comment: I think your computation is incorrect. Wolfram Alpha computes the arc length (which is equal to the hausdorff 1-measure) of your $\gamma$ on $[0,1]$ to be about $1.35$.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I made some dumb typos. Here is the correct version of the counter example: The curve $\gamma(t) = t \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{t})$ for $t > 0$ and $\gamma(0) = 0$ isn't rectifiable on $[0,1]$. But since $\gamma([0,1]) \subseteq [-1,1]$, it follows $\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([0,1])) \leq \mathcal{H}^1([-1,1]) = 2$.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. I thought you were giving an function that contradicted the accepted answer. The reason is your $\gamma$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following theorem from [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rectifiable_curve):

> **Theorem.** A set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is the image of a rectifiable curve if and only if it is compact, connected, and $\mathcal{H}^1(E)<\infty$.

As $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, we know that $\gamma([a,b])$ is both compact and connected.

Now consider two cases: $\gamma([a,b])$ has a rectifiable parameterization, or it does not.

In case it does not, then the above theorem tells us that $\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([a,b]))=\infty$, and so the inequality trivially holds.

If it does, denote this by $\zeta:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and find $a',b'\in[a,b]$ such that $\zeta(a')=\gamma(a)$ and $\zeta(b')=\gamma(b)$. Suppose without loss of generality that $a'<b'$. Then

$$\lVert\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)\rVert=\lVert\zeta(b')-\zeta(a')\rVert\leq\mathcal{H}^1(\zeta([a',b']))\leq\mathcal{H}^1(\zeta([a,b]))=\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([a,b])),$$

and the inequality holds.

Comment: There's a subtle issue here. Just because $\gamma$ isn't rectifiable, it doesn't mean that $\gamma([a,b])$ isn't the image of *any* rectifiable curve. So, $\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma([a,b]))$ isn't necessarily infinite, notably if $\gamma$ has lots of overlaps.

Comment: However, if $\gamma$ is also *injective*, then I believe your conclusion still holds, as your source points out. But, the question doesn't add injectivity as a hypothesis.

Comment: I think the case of a non-injective rectifiable curve isn't immediately covered, so I think an adjustment is needed.

Comment: @Sambo not sure how I missed that, but you are, of course, correct. I edited my answer, and I believe it should be correct now